# Elasticsearch simple function_score query is very slow

Tags: java, performance, elasticsearch

I'm running a query that looks like the following, only with many Filters:

```
{
  "size": 30,
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "query": {
            "match_all": {}
          }
        }
      },
      "script_score": {
        "script": "( doc['num'].value <= 3 || Math.random() < 1/doc['num'].value ) ? Math.random() : 0"
      },
      "boost_mode": "replace"
    }
  }
}
```

and am seeing run times about 10 times slower than without a Function Score Script, even when using all possible filters.

We are running Elastic version 1.0.0 and using Java API (package org.elasticsearch.client)

Is there any way to achieve a similar result with better performance? The links for "Native Java Scripts" in the Elasticsearch tutorials seems broken.

Comment: running into the same problem. Did you find a solution to it yosi?

Comment: I had to drop this issue for now, but I've been told that upgrading to a version that uses groovy instead of mvel could help, see: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/simple-function-score-query-shows-very-poor-performance/274